# Unsing ranger fm, how can I preview a file's thumbnail

Tags: command-line, bash, ranger

I have images in HEIC format on my Synology NAS. I installed ranger in a docker container, and I can preview most videos and images (connecting using iTerm on mac), but HEIC is not supported.

Synology already creates thumbnails for the files, in `@eaDir/IMAGE_FILE.HEIC/SYNOFILE_THUMB_M.jpg`, and  I want to show that instead. Any ideas how I can do that?

In `scope.sh` I tried changing the `IMAGE_CACHE_PATH` to point to the thumbnail, hoping that the image viewer will pick it up, but that didn't work.

Here is my non-functioning code:

```
image/heic)
   echo "start heic">>/root/out.txt
   echo "FILE_PATH ${FILE_PATH}" >> /root/out.txt
   echo "IMAGE_CACHE_PATH b4 ${IMAGE_CACHE_PATH}" >> /root/out.txt
   FILE_NAME=$(basename ${FILE_PATH})
   DIR_NAME=$(dirname ${FILE_PATH})
   IMAGE_CACHE_PATH="${DIR_NAME}/@eaDir/${FILE_NAME}/SYNOFILE_THUMB_M.jpg"
   echo "THUMB_PATH ${THUMB_PATH}" >> /root/out.txt
   ## cp -f "$THUMB_PATH" "$IMAGE_CACHE_PATH"
   ## convert "${THUMB_PATH}" "${IMAGE_CACHE_PATH}"
   echo "IMAGE_CACHE_PATH af ${IMAGE_CACHE_PATH}" >> /root/out.txt
   exit 6;;
```